# <apex:actionFunction> tag does NOT work as expected without reRender attribute

Tags: actionfunction

I was trying to find out what was wrong with the actionFunction tag since half a day only to realise that it does not work without the attribute reRender, which is not documented anywhere.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="callSubmit" action="{!callSubmitAction}" reRender="messagePanel"/>
```

Did you guys experience this any time?

Comment: To my experience it should work. If you don't specify the reRender attribute the entire page will be refreshed.

Comment: @georgethomas, The action method in the controller was NOT getting invoked and the only way to make it call was to add the reRender attribute, spent half a day to discover this :(

Answer (score 3):

If you're passing parameters then yep, unfortunately it's always been like that! [I blogged about it nearly 5 years ago](http://www.laceysnr.com/apexactionfunction-and-apexparam-or-how/) and it's consistantly been my most popular post!

If you look at the JavaScript functions generated by the Visualforce page renderer they just don't have any parameters if you don't include a `rerender` attribute.

Comment: I used the tag without the parameters.   Unfortunately, I end up discovering many such limitations in SF platform which cannot be rationalised, makes a developer's life difficult since you end up wasting lot of time not learning anything in the end.

Comment: The platform definitely has it's quirks. Often these days it's easier to use some of the newer technologies such as visualforce javascript remoting and similar.

Comment: Be interesting to hear the reasoning behind the likely SFDC Tier 3 response of 'Working as designed'.   :-)