# oncomplete does NOT work when used with <apex:ActionFunction>

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:actionFunction name="submitExpJS" action="{!submitExpenses}"  
    oncomplete="refreshMe();" reRender="messagePanel"/>  

<script>
function refreshMe() {    
    alert('refresh');  
}  
</script>
```

The function `refreshMe()` is not getting invoked.

Comment: Did you check if your action function is getting invoked as well or not?

Comment: It does! I tried this attribute oncomplete with a plain <apex:commandButton> and it works fine, it is just in the combination of <apex:actionFunction> that it remains silent. My intention is to refresh the page after calling an action function, i also tried PageReference.redirect from the action method, that also did not work. As an alternative, I wanted to try a javascript refresh function, which is also not working :(.

Comment: If your only purpose is to refresh the page after calling the actionFunction, you can simply remove the reRender attribute of the actionFunction tag and in your controller make the return type to be void. But as @Salesforcesmarty as mentioned, I also doubt about whether your actionfunction is getting invoked at all.

Comment: actionFunction does NOT work without reRender, have a look at my recent post about it http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/114559/apexactionfunction-tag-does-not-work-as-expected-without-rerender-attribute. Actionfunction is definetely getting called, it is updating the records, but the problem is, i need a manual Refresh to reflect the changes on the page. The page consists of a list with editable fields and 'Save' button.

Comment: @ShaliniMendu is your JS code inside `<script >` tag ?

Comment: very much! @sfdcweb

Comment: @ShaliniMendu is it worked ?

Comment: No..it did not work..i was just commenting that the js code is very much inside <script> tag

Comment: @ShaliniMendu Can you check browser console if you are getting any javascript error?

Comment: I double checked it now, there are no js errors.

Comment: @ShaliniMendu Can you put console.log statement instead of alert statement in your refreshMe function. May be your browser is blocking popups, Just a guess.

Comment: Please post the complete VF code and controller.

Comment: try one thing use `apex:pagemessage` and `rerender` that. May be you are getting any exception.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I would post this working sample code that I tried in my Developer edition org.

Controller:

```
public with sharing class SimplePageController {

    public Integer i{get;set;}

    public SimplePageController(){
        i =0;
    }

    public void justIncrement(){
        i = i+1;
        System.debug('From doNothing method on the controller');
    }

}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="SimplePageController" showHeader="false" Sidebar="false">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel id="someDiv">
            <apex:outputText value="{!i}"></apex:outputText>
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <a href="#" onclick="actionFunctionJS();">Click Here</a> 
        <apex:actionFunction name="actionFunctionJS" 
                                action="{!justIncrement}" 
                                oncomplete="onCompleteJSFunction();" 
                                reRender="someDiv">
        </apex:actionFunction>
    </apex:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onCompleteJSFunction(){
            alert('From onCompleteJSFunction method');
        }
    </script>   
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I wish i could paste the code, but it is 100's of lines and it would be too cluttering here.. This is something i noticed,                                                    1.oncomplete method is occasionally getting invoked and there is no pattern that i could relate it to.                                                                                       2. when i update the list, it is taking a while to update the list, so even if i click on refresh, it is taking 2-3 refresh's to actually show the updated values, not sure what is going on..

Comment: @ShaliniMendu, Unfortunately the information you provided is not sufficient enough to help you. The code you posted in the question should work fine unless there are other conditions as you mentioned in this comment. If you can create a simple and short replica of your problem may be people can pitch in more. Thanks!

Comment: @Shalini Mendu  Just post your  <apex:command button part here else where you invoke the "submitExpJS"  javascript function name.

Comment: @bharat, this is a very old post. I must have got it fixed somehow :). Thank you anyway